# Postgres support for UUID

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, uuid, sequelize

My understanding is that Postgres supports UUID data type out-of-the-box. I'm running Postgres on Amazon RDS with Engine version 10.6 and am scratching my head as to why the following commands are not behaving as expected:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Tenants" 
(
    "id" UUID NOT NULL , 
    "domain" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    "name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
    "schema" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, 
    "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

The critical part here is that I'm creating `"id" UUID NOT NULL`. So far, so good. Or so I thought.

Next, I'm trying to add an entry:

```
INSERT INTO "Tenants" ("id","domain","name","schema","createdAt","updatedAt") 
VALUES 
(
    '3b6b220b-2690-4279-8343-cbe6167f7596',
    'test1.stage-domain.io',
    'Test1','test1',
    '2019-02-25 14:29:33.475 +00:00',
    '2019-02-25 14:29:33.475 +00:00') 
RETURNING *;
```

and surprisingly the following error shows up:

> SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for integer:
>   "3b6b220b-2690-4279-8343-cbe6167f7596

Sure enough, if I go to PGAdmin, I'm seeing that the column has not been set to UUID, rather it has been set to an integer:

[image]

The dropdown shown in this picture does not even contain a UUID type.

The weirdest part is that I created a different Postgresql server on RDS last night and everything actually worked just fine in that instance.

**My question:** How can I get my database to recognize the UUID type when creating the Tenants table?

Comment: Are you saying that you manually ran that CREATE TABLE statement and the column was created as an `integer`in the backround? How and where did you run that CREATE TABLE statement?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble in the long run than they are worth it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I ran a script (using Sequelize for node.js) on my local machine, but with a connection to my RDS instance. I don't know if it was background or not, but would that affect things? Yeah, in the end I just ended up with an integer column for "id" when as far as I can see I ran a CREATE TABLE with type UUID for "id".

Comment: Please try to drop your table before to execute `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` or remove the `IF NOT EXIST` part

Comment: Maybe your obfuscation layer (sequelize) changed that somehow.

Comment: You used `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ... `, so the obvious explanation would be that a table of the same name already existed, just with `integer` instead of `uuid`, hence the statement did nothing, as instructed.

Answer (score 2):

just typecast id value like this

```
postgres@localhost:test> create table "Tenants"                                     
 (                                                                                  
     "id" UUID NOT NULL ,                                                           
     "domain" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,                                         
     "name" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,                                                  
     "schema" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,                                         
     "createdAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL,                                 
     "updatedAt" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id")              
 );                                                                                 
CREATE TABLE                                                                        
Time: 0.048s                                                                        


postgres@localhost:test> INSERT INTO "Tenants" ("id","domain","name","schema","createdAt","updatedAt")
 VALUES ('3b6b220b-2690-4279-8343-cbe6167f7596'::UUID, 'test1.stage-domain.io', 'Test1','test1', '2019-02-25 14:29:33.475 +00:00','2019-02-25 14:29:33.475 +00:00') ;
INSERT 0 1
Time: 0.004s
```

hope this helps